# How to Access permissionSet from PermissionSetGroup/Profile to see if a user can access an object

Tags: profile, permission-sets, permission-set-groups

I need to verify if a user can access in Read/Write object Account.
I understand there are multiple ways to give access to an object:

- by the PermissionSet
- by the PermissionGroup
- by the profile

So, how to do that?

**PermissionSet**
I did

```
SELECT Name, Id  FROM PermissionSet where id in 
  (SELECT PermissionSetId FROM    PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId = '<UserId>')'


SELECT SobjectType, ParentId, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit" +
                                 FROM ObjectPermissions
                                 WHERE ParentId in (%s) and SobjectType ='Account'
```

Then, I verify if I have a PermissionRead and a PermissionEdit (one PermissionRead means I have the read access)

**PermissionGroup**
But what about the PermissionGroup? According to the API, I should do something like

```
SELECT SobjectType, ParentId, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit" +
    FROM ObjectPermissions 
WHERE Parent.PermissionSetGroup.DeveloperName = ???
```

Where is the relation between the user and the PermissionSetGroup?

**Profile**:
To get the user's profile, I can use this request

```
SELECT profileId FROM USER WHERE  userName='<UserName>'
```

==> It's not possible to query by the UserId?

In the profile, I see a field "PermissionsPermissionName", but this is a Boolean ? And what the tip "To get a list of available permissions in SOAP API, use describeSObjects()" means? Does it mean that I select tne Name, and inside the answer, somewhere, I will see a list of permissionName, that I can use as a ParentId in the table "ObjectPermission"?
I see that in a question

```
SELECT Id from PermissionSet where ProfileId = '<ProfileId>'
```

So, is the query

```
SELECT SobjectType, ParentId, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit
   FROM ObjectPermissions where ParentId in (SELECT Id from PermissionSet where ProfileId = '<ProfileId')
```

Thank you for your help,

Comment: what's the context of needing to verify this for a given user (ex. LWC)? The reason I ask is that there's ways in apex of [enforcing object and field permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_perms_enforcing.htm) if your goal is to respect user's permissions in your LWC/Apex.

Comment: It is a bit unclear from your question, but I am assuming you're after `OLS/FLS` as opposed to record access and sharing. For `OLS/FLS` the easiest thing to do if you have a specific User Id is to ask Tooling API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_userentityaccess.htm

Comment: Hello Kris, 
The context is our application will read query, read, write objects. We want to be sure that the permission is correct. We faced a lot of time where the application want to access an object and get a PermissionDenied. So, we want to build a dashbord to say "Attention, you don't have a Read permission on Account, integration will failed".

As you see, it's to anticipate operations.
So, how to do that?

Comment: Hello Zaitsman. 
Hum, I don't see the relation between the UserEntityAccess and the relation. 
To know is a user is registered in a PermissionSetGroup, I need to do a query in UserEntityAccess?